# Understanding Feed Forward Neural Network Output

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, feed-forward

I have build a feed forward neural network with 3 hidden layers for regression problem. The metrics I'm using for validation is MAPE. Following are the model parameters

```
#Define the model
NN_model = Sequential()

# The Input Layer :
NN_model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer='normal',input_dim = X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))

# The Hidden Layers :
NN_model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
NN_model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
NN_model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))

# The Output Layer :
NN_model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear'))

# Compile the network :
NN_model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
##NN_model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
NN_model.summary()
```

The sample output looks like the following

```
Train on 18000 samples, validate on 4500 samples
Epoch 1/500
18000/18000 [==============================] - 3s 148us/step - loss: 672.5252 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 672.5252 - val_loss: 29.3799 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 29.3799

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 29.37992, saving model to Weights-001--29.37992.hdf5
Epoch 2/500
18000/18000 [==============================] - 2s 133us/step - loss: 739.9019 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 739.9019 - val_loss: 220.4918 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 220.4918

Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 29.37992
Epoch 3/500
18000/18000 [==============================] - 2s 129us/step - loss: 840.8005 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 840.8005 - val_loss: 18.5716 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 18.5716
```

My question is, in each epoch I see mean absolute percentage error and validation mean absolute percentage error. The later seems to be lower which is what I expect, Why is mean absolute percentage error so different and much higher than validation mean absolute percentage error?

Also, why is validation mean absolute percentage error fluctuating so much?

Appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model is not able to learn anything at all. Did you check your input-data?

Another problem could be that the gradients are to huge, which leads to a "no convergence behaviour". Therefore your loss is just "randomly" fluctuating.

So check your training data, try to scale it and try to use a different loss function! Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I definitely see its something to do with the training data. I using the same model parameters on a housing prize dataset available online and it fit perfectly. the training and validation error converged around 5%. Also, like I said above training error almost remains close to validation error till about first 60% of the data and blows up in the last 20%. When I set validation_split = 0.5 the error reverses. Training error is now same as validation error I was seeing before and validation error has blown up.

Answer (score 0):

The MAPE may be fairly low-ish because there isn't much spread in terms of input values.

Lets pretend we're talking about classical linear regression to make things easier to visualize. Unfortunately, you happen to be running your linear regression on a nice, classical sigmoid - zero to one, with an inflection point at 0.5, from `-inf` to `inf`.

Your *best possible effort* will be a line defined as `0x+0.5`. You simply *physically cannot* do any better with the model you are using. And yet, your MAPE will be at 50%, not something crazy like 10000%.

That model is utter garbage, of course, but its *wrongness* is constrained to a fairly small range of values.

Now, with a DNN, it's trickier, because you have all those extra dimensions to worry about, but it might be a decent lead for debugging your model.

As far as fluctuations go, hard to tell ATM - you've just shown the first three epochs, it may still be trying to find its footing on the data. I'd see if the issue persists during further training before making any diagnoses.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried removing the outliers and also tried unskewing the data the validation error dropped significantly. However what I'm observing is the training error almost remains close to validation error till about first 60% of the data and blows up in the last 20%. When I set validation_split = 0.5 the error reverses. Training error is now same as validation error I was seeing before and validation error has blown up. I see its something to do with data but not able to exactly identify the data point causing it. Does it ring a bell from your experience?